# Calling Modal When a Button is Clicked

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.6, laravel-blade

In a table the name, comment and an edit button for each item returned from my items collection is displayed. When clicking the edit button is, a modal with a form for updating the item should be called.

**Issue**

If there is more than one item returned from the collection, only the last item's edit button calls the modal but the edit button for others does nothing. I need help in fixing my code so that the edit button will always call the modal no matter how many items are in the collection.

**Items Table List**

```
<div class="col-12 table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($items as $item)
            <tr class="text-muted">
                <td class="text-capitalize">{{ $item->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->comment }}</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-custom-one" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editItem{{$item->id}}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i>&nbsp; Edit</button>&nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editItem{{$item->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="/home/items/{{$item->id}}/update" method="POST">
                @method('PUT')
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{$item->name}}" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="comment">Comment</label>
                    <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="5">{{$item->comment}}</textarea>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom-two">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a little minor change in your code. think something like this. you have to call the modal inside the loop. now you can do it by defining this modal in a function or by doing hard coding. I think this will help

```
<div class="col-12 table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($items as $item)
            <tr class="text-muted">
                <td class="text-capitalize">{{ $item->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->comment }}</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-custom-one" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editItem{{$item->id}}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i>&nbsp; Edit</button>&nbsp;
<div class="modal fade" id="editItem{{$item->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="/home/items/{{$item->id}}/update" method="POST">
                @method('PUT')
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{$item->name}}" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="comment">Comment</label>
                    <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="5">{{$item->comment}}</textarea>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom-two">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: That fixed it but is this good coding? Just wondering if there are better ways to do this that optimizes my code.

Comment: At the beginning thinking of optimization will kill your time. just go on. optimizations thing will come automatically with time